# Error in autowiring Beans despite declare in the xml file when testing

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I have the beans.xml as follows:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2" />

        <!-- Hibernate part of assignment 2 -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="mappingResources">
                <list>
                    <value>hibernate/Course.hbm.xml</value>
                    <value>hibernate/Student.hbm.xml</value>
                    <value>hibernate/Degree.hbm.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                <!--  
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                -->

                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>

                     <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                 </props>
            </property>
         </bean>

         <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">  
         <!--  
            <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver"/>    
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:inf5750;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"/>
            <property name="user" value="sa"/>
            <property name="password" value=""/>
       -->

    <!-- The postgres configuration is commented out. Left here as a hint for future assignments -->

            <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql:inf5750"/>
            <property name="user" value="dhis"/>
            <property name="password" value="dhis"/>

        </bean>

        <!-- ContenNegotiationViewResolver -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
            <property name="mediaTypes">
                <map>
                    <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
                    <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
                    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="viewResolvers">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
                    </bean>
                      <!--  
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Mashaller">
                            <property name="classesToBeBound">
                                <list>
                                    <value>no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.Student</value>
                                    <value>no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.Course</value>
                                    <value>no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.Degree</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                    -->
                </list>
            </property>

            <property name="defaultViews">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
                </list>
            </property>
            <!--  
            <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
             -->
        </bean>


        <bean id="studentSystem" 
        class="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.service.impl.DefaultStudentSystem">
        </bean>

        <bean id="studentService" 
        class="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.service.impl.DefaultStudentSystem">
        </bean>

        <bean id="courseDao" class="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateCourseDao">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="studentDao" class="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateStudentDao">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="degreeDao" class="no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.hibernate.HibernateDegreeDao">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

And the test file:

```
 package no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.StudentDAO;
import no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.model.Degree;
import no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.model.Student;

//@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:src/test/testbeans.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:/META-INF/assignment2/beans.xml"})
//@Transactional
public class StudentDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDAO studentDao;
    private int studentId;
    private Student student;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        student = new Student();
        student.setName("Tan Tran");
        studentId = studentDao.saveStudent(student);
    }

    //Test cases for assignment 3
    @Test
    public void testSaveLongitude() {
        String longitude;
        longitude = "10.183341";
        student.setLongitude(longitude);
        studentDao.saveStudent(student);
        Student studentTest = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);
        Assert.assertEquals("10.183341", studentTest.getLongitude());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveLatitude() {
        String latitude;
        latitude = "59.7326693";
        student.setLatitude(latitude);
        studentDao.saveStudent(student);
        Student studentTest = studentDao.getStudent(studentId);
        Assert.assertEquals("59.7326693", studentTest.getLatitude());
    }    
}
```

However when running unit test (maven and junit) I got the following errors, I tried all the solutions but it doesn't help at all. In the same project, it worked very perfectly.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.StudentDAOTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.319 sec <<< FAILURE!
testSaveLongitude(no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.StudentDAOTest)  Time elapsed: 0.87 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:333)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultStudentSystem': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.CourseDAO no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.service.impl.DefaultStudentSystem.courseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in URL [file:/home/whitedragon27/assignment3_thdtran/assignment2-deliverable/target/classes/META-INF/assignment2/beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.CourseDAO no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.service.impl.DefaultStudentSystem.courseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in URL [file:/home/whitedragon27/assignment3_thdtran/assignment2-deliverable/target/classes/META-INF/assignment2/beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in URL [file:/home/whitedragon27/assignment3_thdtran/assignment2-deliverable/target/classes/META-INF/assignment2/beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:812)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1215)
    ... 54 more
testSaveLatitude(no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.StudentDAOTest)  Time elapsed: 1.447 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:333)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultStudentSystem': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.CourseDAO no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.service.impl.DefaultStudentSystem.courseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in URL [file:/home/whitedragon27/assignment3_thdtran/assignment2-deliverable/target/classes/META-INF/assignment2/beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.dao.CourseDAO no.uio.inf5750.assignment2.service.impl.DefaultStudentSystem.courseDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in URL [file:/home/whitedragon27/assignment3_thdtran/assignment2-deliverable/target/classes/META-INF/assignment2/beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in URL [file:/home/whitedragon27/assignment3_thdtran/assignment2-deliverable/target/classes/META-INF/assignment2/beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:812)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1215)
    ... 54 more
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException:
>
> Cannot find class
>   [**org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver**]
>
> for bean with name
>       'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0'
>
> defined in URL
>   [file:/home/whitedragon27/assignment3_thdtran/assignment2-deliverable/target/classes/META-INF/assignment2/beans.xml];

The bean.xml is loaded but the required class cannnot be found. You asked for that here:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
```

Not sure if it's in spring-web or spring-mvc, but you are probably missing one of those dependencies in your test classpath.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. However, the StudentDaoTest doesn't need ContenNegotiaingViewResolver (I think), and I created another beans.xml for testing. The problem is the autowiring of StudentDao.

Comment: I can only tell you, what the error message says. If you changed something and get a new error message, that will be a new topic, I'm afraid.

Comment: Read the stack trace it is clearly telling you what is wrong. As @FlorianSchaetz pointed out you are missing a spring dependency. It doesn't matter if the `StudentDao` needs it or not the bean is in the context you are loading and hence you need it available.